# Getting a probability curve (Central Limit Theorem)

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

in a game I play there's a chance to get a good item with 1/1000.
After 3200 runs I only got 1.

So how can I calculate how likely that is and I remember there are graphs which have 1 sigma and 2 sigma as vertical lines and you can tell what you can expect with 90% and 95% sureness.

Sorry if that's asked before, but I don't remember the name of such a graph!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need not necessarily concern yourself with the mentioned graph. What you're actually asking about, is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution. You have a success probability $p= \frac{1}{1000}$ and $n=3200$ trials. So are you asking about the probability of exactly one success ($k=1$)? If this is the case, the numbers are already so high that one should use some approximations ... Or are you asking about at least one success?

Comment: @MattiP. ah, thanks. I'm just wondering how unlucky I am, so the chance of exactly one should be what I want.

Comment: @SAJW : I edited my answer...now it is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an application of the CLT: to apply it should be , $np \geq 5$. We have $np=3.2$; it is low but not very low...say bordeline.

With 95% sureness the interval of what you are expected to find is the following formula

$$[np-2\sqrt{np(1-p)};np+2\sqrt{np(1-p)}]$$

where $p=\frac{1}{1000}$

Substituting  your numbers, you get that your expectation of successes is, with a confidence of 95%

$$[1;5]$$

so you are in the range....

If you want a confidence interval at 90% you must substitute 2 with 1.64

Comment: so if $np$ is less than $2$ it's too low I guess? or where should one draw the line?

Comment: With a probability of 1 on 1000 the number of trial should be at least around 5000. If $np=3$ it's borderline....

Answer (score 1):

The probability of exactly one success is a straightforward expression to evaluate:
$$
\begin{split}
P(\text{exactly 1 success out of 3200 trials}) &= {3200 \choose 1} \left(\frac{1}{1000} \right)^1 \left(1 - \frac{1}{1000} \right)^{3200-1}\\
& \approx 0.1306
\end{split}
$$
The answer is approximately $13\%$. The last term is tricky to evaluate due to the large exponent, but this answer was provided by Wolfram Alpha.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the probability of getting exactly one success follows a Binomial distribution, as in the answer given by Matti P, but as mentioned in that answer, you end up with a difficult computation (at least difficult on a hand calculator, although easy for a system like Mathematica or Wolfram Alpha).  For small probabilities, the Poisson distribution gives a good approximation without the numerical difficulty of the Binomial.

To apply the Poisson distribution, the average number of successes we expect to see in $3200$ trials is $\lambda = 3200 / 1000 = 3.2$.  The probability of exactly $k$ successes is
$$\frac{\lambda^k}{k!} e^{- \lambda}$$
From this formula with $k=1$, the probability of exactly one success is $0.1304$.